# Turn off a Tab Google Colaboratory on Chrome while a bash script file is running in server of google (GPU)

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, drive, google-colaboratory

I'm a newbie in Google Colab.
I loaded all project to my Google Drive
and created a Untitled.ipynb to run a bash script (like terminal)
Actually that .sh file is controlling the .py file in my project

At Untitled.ipynb, I type: !sh my_script.sh but the code runs too long (maximum 3 hours).
How can I turn off that tab (or my computer) and the code is still running and I can get my result later ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Colab doesn't support that sort of non-interactive use.